# Modifying PDO Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

What i have it's a login form in which the user can access via it's credentials or it can access as a guest, but what i want to do it's to identify how he is trying to access to the page, and to have a different PDO connection for each case.

I have a PHP script called `functions.php` in wich the connection it's stored and it looks something like this:

```
//I have created the class Connection and it's setters and getters
$connection = new Connection($host,$user,$pw,$db);
```

And basicly what i want it's to when the user logs as admin to modify this connection like this:

```
if(admin){
   $connection->setUser('Admin');
   $connection->setPassword('Password');
}
```

But since i made a query earlier in the code to check if the user does exist, and i made that query with the same connection but with the `guest` username and password, it won't let me change it. I don't know if i have to `__destruct()` the connection and then create it again, or what should i do.

Comment: you just can overwrite the $connection with a new Connection Object.

Comment: Since i `require` the `functions.php` file in other php scripts wouldn't it overwrite itself back to the default connection as `guest` ?

Comment: sure, for every new request it would be the guest connection again. you need some kind of session management to track the login state and use the right connection accordingly.